# File upload in OpenShift

Tags: file-upload, openshift

I am making an application which will save user uploads (files) in server. When I deploy the application in localhost it runs well, but now I want to do the same in OpenShift.

The path were the files are being saved in my local host is 
`Savefile = "D:/Test/" + Userid + "/" + Savefile + "/";`

How do I change this path in my application after deploying in OpenShift so that it works?

Answer (score 7):

you want to grab the environment variable

$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR

in your code and then write to that path (if you want to keep the file).

If it is only temporary then you can write to /tmp

Comment: Can you please give an example for that from the path which i have mentioned above

Comment: show me the line of code you are using currently for your machine and I will modify it

Comment: i have shared my file upload code in the below link..pls help me https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByVkapqzmC2ZS0RsajNfVTFneUE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: These two line will not work on OpenShift:

saveFile = "D:/test/" + userid + "/" + saveFile + "/";
File ff = new File(saveFile);

you need to write the data to the $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR. Please look at the documentation talking about using environment variables and writable locations

Answer (score 0):

Run this code once to check if there is a default data-directory. If it exists use it as data directory.

```
String property = System.getProperty("jboss.server.data.dir");
if (property != null) {
    boolean exists = new File(property).exists();
    System.out.println("exists: " + exists); // if the file exists you can use it as data directory for your uploads
}
```